# Count the number of lines of code changed between time periods

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

For a single project, I would like to know the number of lines of code changed within a rolling time period.

We are using Jenkins and Java, and I am looking for for some kind of Jenkins plugin or report that would give me a report on demand.

The goal will be to determine if there is a relationship between bugs found and number of lines of code changed, and more importantly, to do this comparison between different projects.

Comment: I see some downvotes, but I see no requests for information that would help me to improve my question.  Please some questions to assist.

Comment: I think people are having hard time figuring out what exactly you need (especially before edit 1 hour ago). Also this skirts the "recommend a library/tool for me" offtopic category. I would try to provide more explanation , perhaps an imaginary example case, to clarify what you need. Also telling what you have found so far might help people to get your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here is one idea:

1. Write a script which will list the changes from SCM checkout and create a file. Add build step to run this script, and add its output file to artifacts of the build.
2. Produce whatever test report as usual, and add as artifact.
3. Trigger a downstream job, which gives these artifacts to another script, which combines them to produce your bugs/changes report.

What scripting language to use, doesn't matter as long as it has good support for the necessary file formats. If you have no preference, and know some Java, and are going to use Jenkins for a long time, then Groovy might be a good choice, because you can also write Jenkins plugins with it, or just tap into Jenkins' APIs directly. If you are not really a programmer, then Python might be a good choice. If you have a Perl expert in the project, then that might be good. And so on.

Comment: I was hoping for something more plug and play, but this answer does illustrate the difficulty of implementing my request.