# Count Number of Lines of Code Older Than 1 Year

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to count the number of lines in a repository that are older than some timestamp (say, 1 year)?

CLOC seemed fine for total lines of code, but wasn't clear if I could add a where filter and the below post was a bit confusingly written.

POST: [Count the number of lines of code changed between time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594604/count-the-number-of-lines-of-code-changed-between-time-periods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do a blame of each file showing the date of each line as seconds since UNIX epoch (--date=raw) and then you can know if it's more than one year old.